# Make one panel close when another is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to make it for if one of these panels is open, it'll close when you've clicked on another panel. *I looked at some other questions similar to mine but it seems they all uses a different method for the panels.*

Heres a Fiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/3q87y2u8/

Heres the JS:

```
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.maxHeight){
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
   }
}
```

I'd also like to get the '+' to change color when hovered over. Kinda like the text currently does. I cant seem to call it out right in the CSS though.

Thank You!

Comment: why dont you use js libraries like jquery?

Answer (score 1):

A more readable and more efficient way would be to simply hold a reference to the previously toggled accordion item.

When onclick is called, you will first want to check if cur is the clicked on panel. That way, toggling cur will just close it. Next, set cur to null, so it won't open up the previous panel when you click a different panel. Then make sure to return out of the function. Note that you have to do this before the nonnull check for cur.

Otherwise, check the now active item to current to make sure it is not null, then toggle both cur and this. Wrap it up by setting cur to this, so next time it can do it all over again!

Also, here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d7smh9ru/4/

```
var cur = null;
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {

    // Only close already open panel
    if (cur == this) {
      toggleItem(cur);
      cur = null;
      return;
    }

    // Close current panel, and open this panel
    if (cur) {
      toggleItem(cur);
    }

    toggleItem(this);
    cur = this;
  }
}

function toggleItem(item) {
  item.classList.toggle("active");
  var panel = item.nextElementSibling;
  if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
  } else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
}
```

Comment: This combined with what others said seems to have gotten me just about where i need to be thank you all! One more problem im having with your js here. It seems to work super smooth and clean, just what i wanted! But now if you open one you cant close it. If you open another itll close which ever one was open but you cant click an open one to close it. Its a small thing but there wouldnt be much point in having the '-' sign there to show people it can close xD Here is what i got right now if you have any suggestions: https://jsfiddle.net/d7smh9ru/

Comment: Oh, whoops! I'll edit the answer with my suggestions.

Comment: Seems to work! thank you. And i deff understand it a bit more now

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element that is currently active and then remove the active class like so:

```
// Is an array of elements matching the selector
var active = document.getElementsByClassName('active');

// If there are any matching elements and it is not the same one that has just been clicked on
if (active.length && active[0] !== this) {
    active[0].classList.remove('active');
}
```

One side comment (you are of course free to ignore!): for the max-height you don't need to figure out the height (unless of course it interferes with how you have your page structure already set up). You can just use some large height and since it's the max-height you are setting and not the height it will automatically go to its natural height. You can also achieve this using just CSS, including the animation, and updating the hover text on the plus sign is included below as well.

```
// Set regular state height to 0 and add a transition effect
.panel {
    max-height: 0px;
    transition: max-height .25s ease;
}

// For whatever button is active find the adjacent panel and set its max height and a transition effect
.active + .panel {
  max-height: 250px;
  transition: max-height .25s ease;
}

// Here is where you change the color of the active and hovered plus/minus sign
button.accordion.active:after,
button.accordion:hover:after {
  color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xz2mpzg2/1/
https://jsfiddle.net/xz2mpzg2/2/

Comment: Ah thank you this worked! and ty for side comment. With what you have right now in your fiddle. When you open another div which ever one was previously open will kinda just sit there for a second while the other opens then ill close after. It kinda looks buggy. I messed with the timing for the transition but it doesnt seem to fix it. Any ideas? Other than that its perfect! @Pango

Comment: Hmm, I'm not able to get that much of a delay, but try setting max-height: 1px instead of 0. I'm not 100% sure about that, let me know if that does anything and if not I can take another look.

Comment: It didnt seem to fix it. It might look a hair better but its basically the same i think

Comment: @WarrenBreedlove I cut the max height down to a smaller number. It looked like the largest height div was about 200px so I set it to 250 to be safe, you should adjust as necessary. If you were worried about it, you could reimplement the idea of the JS you had to find the height and set the max height. If you didn't care about the animation you can just set height: 0 and then height: auto when active (and remove the transitions).

Answer (score 0):

shrink all the divs right after the button click. The jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/3q87y2u8/3/

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
            var i;

                for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                    acc[i].onclick = function() {
                    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panels=document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
    for (j = 0; j < panels.length; j++) {
    panels[j].style.maxHeight = null;
    }
                    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
                    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            } 
           }
        }
```

Comment: that seems to work but then there background colors kinda bug out, and dont go back to how it should be. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/cc1hj0kn/

Comment: It also wont let you close a panel you just opened

Answer (score 0):

Simply with jQuery you could easily use:

**A.)** [.toggle();](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

B.) [.change();](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

*C.) [.addClass();](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) / [removeClass();](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)*

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0ve5qu2/).

I'll go through each change I made, and each statement is also commented, but as a general principal, I changed your code to use a wrapper `div` around each group of buttons/text, and I put the text inside an inner `div` so it would respect `max-height`.  Instead of the event handler modifying its next sibling, which would fail, e.g., if your paragraphs were individually enclosed in `p` tags and not line-broken using `br` tags inside your `p`s.  This also made it trivial to implement the hover-changes-plus-color effect, using the parent's `:hover` pseudoclass.

So, if you change your button/text groups from:

```
<button class="accordion">Home</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis             nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div class="panel">
  <button class="accordion">Home</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis           nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and update your CSS, changing your `panel` class to `content` (previously beginning on line 50 of your JSFiddle):

```
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 220px;
  font-size: 10px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

and use CSS to set the max-height to 0 on non-opened panels

```
div.panel:not(.opened) > .content {
  max-height: 0;
}
```

You can then set your event listeners on the buttons, and simply toggle the parent's `opened` class:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion')
  .forEach(element => {
    element.onclick = function() {

      // first, iterate over other open panels and close them...
      // note: using Array.from(...) so we can filter the result below.
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.panel.opened'))

        // ...but skip the clicked panel, which will be dealt with below
        // [edit] we filter here so we can close an already-open panel
        .filter(panel => panel !== this.parentNode)

        .forEach(panel => {

          // toggle the 'opened' class, forcing `false`
          panel.classList.toggle('opened', false)

          // and remove styling that was set on the element itself
          panel.querySelector('.content').style.maxHeight = null;
        });

      // now toggle the clicked panel's 'opened' class and capture its new value
      const toggled = this.parentNode.classList.toggle('opened');

      // reference the new div.content, inside the button's parent
      const content = this.parentNode.querySelector('.content');

      // and either fix its max height or unset it, depending on new state
      content.style.maxHeight = toggled? `${content.scrollHeight}px` : null;
    }
  });
```

Finally, if you want to change the '+' color on highlight, now you can do so using the `:hover` pseudoclass on `.panel`:

```
div.panel:hover > button.accordion:after {
  color: red;
}
```